# How to access previous turtles interactions in Netlogo?

Tags: time, netlogo, history, interaction

I am writing a model in which agents interact with each other and they either cooperate or defect. They then update their cooperation level with their partner based on the interaction they had, and I managed to implement this as follows:

```
to random-matching ; randomly match agents
  while [not matched?] [ ; check that I have not been matched yet
    set partner one-of agents with [not matched?] ; select one agent from those who have not been matched yet
    if (partner != nobody and [myID] of partner != myID) [ ; if there is still someone who has been matched and who is not myself
      set matched? true ; then record that I have been matched
      set color white
      set partner-ID [myID] of partner ; save the ID of my partner for the future
      ask partner [ ; and do the same for my partner
        set matched? true
        set color white
        set partner-ID [myID] of myself
        set partner myself
      ]
    ]
  ]
  
  
end

; access the cooperation level of the agent toward the partner
to-report coop-agent-partner
  let coop-agent table:get cooperation-matrix myID  
  let coop table:get coop-agent partner-ID
  report coop
end

; access the cooperation level of the partner toward the agent
to-report coop-partner-agent
  let coop-partner table:get cooperation-matrix partner-ID
  let coop table:get coop-partner myID
  report coop
end
  


to interact ; define whether the interaction is a cooperation or not
  ; check that I did not interact already with my partner
  if not interacted? [
    
  ; let's check what I do
    let j random-float 1 * 100
    let coop-% cooperation-level + coop-agent-partner
    ifelse (j <= coop-%) [
      set action-self "C"
      ask partner [set action-partner "C" ]
    ][
      set action-self "D"
      ask partner [set action-partner "D" ]
    ]
    
  ; and what my partner does
    let k random-float 1 * 100
    let coop-partner-% [cooperation-level] of partner + coop-partner-agent
    
    ifelse (j <= coop-partner-%) [
      ask partner [set action-self "C" ]
      set action-partner "C"
    ][
      ask partner [set action-self "D" ]
      set action-partner "D"
    ]
    
  ;save the outcome of the interaction
    ifelse (action-self = "C" and action-partner = "C")[
      set interaction-outcome "C"
      set current-goal (current-goal + 1)
    ]
    [
      set interaction-outcome "D"
    ]  
  ]
end

; update the agents cooperation according to the current interaction

to update-cooperation
  
  if not updated-coop? [
    ifelse (action-partner = "C")[ ; if the partner cooperated
      let coop-agent table:get cooperation-matrix myID  
      let coop-a-p table:get coop-agent partner-ID
      set coop-a-p (coop-a-p / 2) + update_cooperation_direct
      
      if debug-int? [print coop-a-p]
    ][
      let coop-agent table:get cooperation-matrix myID  
      let coop-a-p table:get coop-agent partner-ID
      set coop-a-p (coop-a-p / 2) - update_cooperation_direct
      
    ]
    ifelse (action-self = "C")[
      ask partner[ ; if the interaction was a cooperation
        let coop-agent table:get cooperation-matrix myID  
        let coop-a-p table:get coop-agent partner-ID
        set coop-a-p (coop-a-p / 2) + update_cooperation_direct
      
      ]
    ][
      ask partner [
        let coop-agent table:get cooperation-matrix myID  
        let coop-a-p table:get coop-agent partner-ID
        set coop-a-p (coop-a-p / 2) - update_cooperation_direct
        
      ]
    ]
    
    ; record that both the agent and the partner have updated their cooperation score
    
    set updated-coop? true
    ask partner [set updated-coop? true]
  
  ]

end
```

I now need agents to store the interaction they had and their partner ID in a variable that keeps track of WHEN that happened, so I need to store, for each agent, when the interaction happened (tick), with whom they interacted (partner-ID) and what the partner did (action-partner).
Is there an easy way to do that?
I think I already over-complicated the code I wrote up to now and I wanted to ask for some help.
I just started coding in Netlogo and I am trying to translate my code from Matlab, where this was implemented as a matrix with a width equal to the round the interaction happened.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You could continue to use tables indexed by the partner and the value stored is a list with all the details you want. However, the usual purpose of moving to a different language is because the new language better conceptualises the problem. In this case, you are trying to replicate the Matlab structure, which uses matrices because it doesn't have any concept of an agent. If you have everything actually represented as agents, then you can use links for the interactions and the link can store when and action information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jen. Would you be able to provide an example for that? I am extremely new to Netlogo and I am struggling understanding how to use the agents properly (and also links in this case)

Comment: The models library has an example of n-player iterated prisoners dilemma which is probably the best starting point. Then you could have a look at OpenABM - the search term 'prisoner' gets 14 results (see https://www.comses.net/codebases/?query=prisoner)